# Angular $scope variable not setting on callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't figure out why the scope variable is not being assigned.

```
<script src="https://js.paystack.co/v1/inline.js"></script>
<button type="button" ng-click="checkout()">Checkout</button>
<div ng-show='txref'>
   <h2>Payment successful!</h2> Transaction reference: {{txref}}
</div>
```

JS

```
 //this function triggers when the button above is clicked. Everything else except assigning the reference to $scope.txref
$scope.checkout = function() {
   var handler = PaystackPop.setup({
     key: 'pk_test_1c828c1b8d9a98232c90d7aa6c418953c8150096',
     email: 'customer@email.com',
     amount: 10000 * 100,
     ref: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1),
     callback: function(response){
         console.log(response.reference)  //works
         alert(response.reference)  //works
         $scope.txref = response.reference; //doesn't work until you click the button again
     },
     onClose: function(){
         alert('window closed');
      }
   });
   handler.openIframe();
}
```

Everything in the callback works except for assigning the reference to $scope.txref. It refuses to work, but when you click the button again, everything is normal. I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Initiate txref. `$scope.txref = '';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$scope.$apply()` to update the digest. This should fix your issue. Also initiate your scope variable:

```
$scope.checkout = function() {
   $scope.txref = '';
   var handler = PaystackPop.setup({
     key: 'pk_test_1c828c1b8d9a98232c90d7aa6c418953c8150096',
     email: 'customer@email.com',
     amount: 10000 * 100,
     ref: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1),
     callback: function(response){
         console.log(response.reference)  //works
         alert(response.reference)  //works
         $scope.txref = response.reference;
         $scope.$apply(); // <---- This should do the work for you
     },
     onClose: function(){
         alert('window closed');
      }
   });
   handler.openIframe();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to wrap your variable assignment with `$timeout` for example, to notify angular about your change:

```
callback: function(response){
     console.log(response.reference)  //works
     alert(response.reference)  //works
     $timeout(function () {
       $scope.txref = response.reference; //doesn't work until you click the button again
     });   
 },
```

and do not forget to inject *$timeout* to your controller, the same way as *$scope* is injected

Comment: This general a bad practice. Have a look in this nice article: https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/top-18-most-common-angularjs-developer-mistakes

Comment: @VassilisPits, thank you for ponting, but please specify which section you are talking about in this article. Since we will not have *$scope* at all in NG2, I personally think it is much better not to use at all *$scope*, but rather *controllerAs* and *this* within controller. In this case *$timeout* is a good solution. Also it is better to use `$scope.$applyAsync` and not `$scope.$apply`

Comment: Check mistake #8. Also this question is not reffered to NG2 but Angularjs 1.x. Btw also the controllerAss (which I prefer also) has nothing to do with performance. Have good day

Comment: I am completely agree that resolving promise within another promise ($q within $timeout) it is very bad practice, I would rewrite var deferred = $q.defer();
      $timeout(function () {
        deferred.resolve(console.log('Data resolve called ' + index));
      }, timeout);
      return deferred.promise; into just return $timeout(console.log('Data resolve called ' + index), timeout); since $timeout is also promise, but it has nothing to do with my answer.

Comment: also please not that OP is dealing with asynchronous callback outside of angular, when page is already loaded, so there is no impact on the page load time. Also $timeout ensures that we do not get „$digest already in progress“ error